# Como extraio a quantidade de pedidos com 5 itens diferentes? Possuo essa query porém está saindo um resultado diferente do esperado

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pedidos.id_pedidos),produtos.nome_produto
FROM pedidos
    INNER JOIN itens_dopedido ON itens_dopedido.id_pedido=pedidos.id_pedidos
    INNER JOIN produtos ON produtos.id_produto=itens_dopedido.id_produto
WHERE nome_produto = (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT(id_pedido)) >= 5));
```

Estão saindo resultados com 4 pedidos diferentes e 1. Alguém pode me explicar o que está acontecendo? Porque eu não entendi.

Comment: Qual o objetivo da sua `query`?

Comment: Considere utilizar a cláusula `HAVING`. É o tipico problema para o qual ela se aplica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer apenas a quantidade de pedidos que tem mais de 5 itens, basta usar uma `subquery` que conte a quantidade de `itens_dopedido` e que seja comparada com o número que você quer:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS quantidade
  FROM pedidos p
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM itens_dopedido i
         WHERE i.id_pedido = p.id_pedidos) >= 5
```

Comment: Vou fazer aqui, muito obrigada :)

Comment: @vivianearaujo caso a resposta tenha lhe atendido não esqueça de marcá-la como correta, assim pessoas com dúvidas similares podem ser beneficiadas pela sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você está fazendo algumas coisas erradas, no where você está comparando nome_produto uma soma aleatório. Você precisa utilizar também a tabela itens_do_pedido, eu fiz um exemplo bem simples com um subselect, eu só não sei na sua tabela qual é o **"id_item_pedido"**, segue exemplo como o select deveria ser feito:

```
SELECT pedidos, nome_produto, qtd_itens_diferentes

  FROM(

    SELECT ped.id_pedidos, p.nome_produto, 
    COUNT(itp.id_item_pedido) AS qtd_itens_diferentes

    FROM pedidos ped

        INNER JOIN itens_dopedido itp
            ON itp.id_pedido = ped.id_pedidos

        INNER JOIN produtos p
            ON p.id_produto = itp.id_produto

    GROUP BY ped.id_pedidos, p.nome_produto 
  )

WHERE qtd_itens_diferentes > 5
```

Comment: No lugar do SUM não deveria ser COUNT?

Comment: Isso mesmo rs, ajustado, espero que tenha te ajudado.